# How to take multiple images using CameraX?

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camerax

My use case is to take two images at one time. first one at 2x zoom and second one at 1x zoom level. Also, I want to save images to files.

My idea of doing it was to take the first image at 2x zoom and when the image is saved set the zoom level at 1x and take the second image when the lens has zoomed to 1x zoom level.

However, when I take the first image the preview is stuck at the first image and callback from setting 1x zoom never happens.

This is how I create the capture use cases.

```
private void createImageCaptureUseCases() {
    ImageCapture imageCapture1 = new ImageCapture.Builder()
        .setCaptureMode(ImageCapture.CAPTURE_MODE_MINIMIZE_LATENCY)
        .build();

    ImageCapture imageCapture2 = new ImageCapture.Builder()
        .setCaptureMode(ImageCapture.CAPTURE_MODE_MINIMIZE_LATENCY)
        .build();

    imageCaptureUseCases.clear();
    imageCaptureUseCases.add(imageCapture1);
    imageCaptureUseCases.add(imageCapture2);
```

This is how I first start the camera session.

```
ListenableFuture<ProcessCameraProvider> cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(getContext());

cameraProviderFuture.addListener(() -> {
    try {
        cameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get();
        preview = new Preview.Builder().build();

        cameraSelector = new CameraSelector.Builder()
            .requireLensFacing(CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK)
            .build();

        Camera camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
            ((LifecycleOwner) this),
            cameraSelector,
            preview,
            imageCapture);

        camera.getCameraControl().setZoomRatio(2f);

        preview.setSurfaceProvider(previewView.createSurfaceProvider(camera.getCameraInfo()));
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {}
}, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(getContext()));
```

this is how the capture images is called.

```
private void captureImage(ImageCapture imageCapture) {

    File pictureFile = ImageUtils.createImageFile(getActivity());
    ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions options = new 
        ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions.Builder(pictureFile).build();

    final Activity activity = getActivity();

    imageCapture.takePicture(options, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(activity),
        new ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onImageSaved(@NonNull ImageCapture.OutputFileResults outputFileResults){
                Log.i("my tag", "image Saved: " + pictureFile.getAbsolutePath());

                int index = imageCaptureUseCases.indexOf(imageCapture);
                cameraProvider.unbind(imageCapture);
                if (index < imageCaptureUseCases.size() - 1) {
                    Camera camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
                    (LifecycleOwner) activity,
                    cameraSelector,
                    imageCaptureUseCases.get(index + 1));

                    ListenableFuture future = camera.getCameraControl().setZoomRatio(1f);
                    future.addListener(() -> captureImage(imageCaptureUseCases.get(index + 1)),
                                    ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(activity));
                } else {
                    createImageCaptureUseCases();
                    cameraProvider.unbindAll();
                    Camera camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
                        (LifecycleOwner) activity,
                        cameraSelector,
                        preview,
                        imageCaptureUseCases.get(0));

                    camera.getCameraControl().setZoomRatio(2f);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(@NonNull ImageCaptureException exception) {
                Log.i("my tag", "image save error: " + pictureFile.getAbsolutePath());
            }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You don't need multiple `ImageCapture` instances to capture an image with 2 zoom ratios, you can use the same instance, `ImageCapture` handles taking a picture and saving it/providing it, irrelevant to parameters such as the zoom ratio.
- Looking at your code sample, it seems you might not being binding a `Preview` use case the second time you try to capture an image (with a different zoom ratio). This would explain why your preview is getting stuck after the first image capture. Keep in mind that an `ImageCapture` use case cannot be bound on its own, it must be bound with at least 1 `Preview` or `ImageAnalysis` use case.

Below is a sample to capture 2 images, each with a different zoom ratio. The code contains some repetition, and is all in 1 block, so it can definitely be improved.

```
    private fun setUpCamera() {
       val mainExecutor = ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this)
       val cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this)
       cameraProviderFuture.addListener(Runnable {
          // Wait for the camera provider to be retrieved
          val cameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()

          // Build your use cases
          val preview = Preview.Builder().build()
          val imageCapture = ImageCapture.Builder().build()

          // Get a camera selector to use
          val cameraSelector = CameraSelector.DEFAULT_BACK_CAMERA

          // Bind the use cases to a lifecycle
          val camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(this, cameraSelector, preview, imageCapture)

          // Set the preview surface provider
preview.setSurfaceProvider(previewView.createSurfaceProvider(camera.cameraInfo))

          // Set the zoom ratio for the first photo
          val cameraControl = camera.cameraControl
          cameraControl.setZoomRatio(1F)

          // When the previewView is clicked, take the photos
          previewView.setOnClickListener {
             imageCapture.takePicture(createOutputFilesOptions(), mainExecutor, object : ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback {
                override fun onImageSaved(outputFileResults: ImageCapture.OutputFileResults) {

                   // First image captured and saved successfully
                   Log.d(TAG, "OnImageSavedCallback.onImageSaved: Image saved with zoom ratio 1F")

                   // Set a new zoom ratio for the second image capture
                   cameraControl.setZoomRatio(2F)

                   // Capture the second picture with a different zoom ratio
                   imageCapture.takePicture(createOutputFilesOptions(), mainExecutor, object : ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback {
                      override fun onImageSaved(outputFileResults: ImageCapture.OutputFileResults) {

                         // Second image captured and saved successfully
                         Log.d(TAG, "OnImageSavedCallback.onImageSaved: Image saved with zoom ratio 2F")
                      }

                      override fun onError(exception: ImageCaptureException) {
                         Log.e(TAG, "OnImageSavedCallback.onError", exception)
                      }
                   })
                }

                override fun onError(exception: ImageCaptureException) {
                   Log.e(TAG, "OnImageSavedCallback.onError", exception)
                }
             })
          }
       }, mainExecutor)
    }
}
```